# Running tests in Parallel based on a dynamically generated array from a beforeAll using Playwright

Tags: playwright

The scenario I'm trying to test is:

- Get an array of elements from the page and read the `url` property of that element
- Test 1 - that the array is not empty
- For Each of these elements

  - Test 2->`number of elements` - Navigate to the url read above and test there are no errors on the page

So far I've got the code working, but only by including the for loop in the second test, which only registers the above as two tests and does not run the second set (ie: the for loop) in parallel.

When trying to make the second set of tests parallel (as I've done in another test that's based on a static array of pages) I end up with the below code, but the second set of tests is not even detected, ie: if I comment out Test 1, `no tests found` is reported.

Here's the code structure I'm trying to use.  As I said above, it is based upon another test that's using a static array of elements that does seem to work as expected.  The main difference with the other test is that *everything* is within the loop and there is no `beforeAll`.  I'm assuming that's where the crux of the issue is.

```
import { test, expect, chromium } from '@playwright/test';

const pages = [];

test.describe('Pages Load', () => {
  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);

    const allPages = await page
      .locator('container id')
      .evaluateAll(($elements) => {
        return $elements.map((element) => {
          const pageTitle = element.querySelector('element id');
          const pageURL = element.getAttribute(
            'attribute id'
          );

          return {
            title: pageTitle,
            url: pageURL,
          };
        });
      });

    allPages.forEach(($page) => {
      pages.push({
        title: $page.title,
        url: $page.url,
      });
    });
  });

  test('Pages exist', () => {
    expect(pages.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });

  test.describe('No errors on pages', () => {
    pages.forEach((page) => {
      test.describe(`${page.title}`, () => {
        test('No errors', async () => {
          // Test goes here
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

---

Update:
I've had a bit more of a play with this and while I know why this code isn't working, I still have no idea how to resolve the issue.

Couple of things I've noticed (and these are just theories/assumptions based on what I've observed):

- Firstly, the reason why the above isn't working is because the array isn't set up by the time it get's to the loop, as the `beforeAll` only appears to happen with each `test`, not the `test.describe`.  While this is just a theory (can't see anything in the documentation proving or disproving this), it does explain why the second test is ignored, because the array.length is 0
- Secondly, when attempting to extract the functionality into a separate function outside of the test, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787926/how-do-i-properly-run-individual-playwright-tests-from-a-dynamic-array-of-built?rq=1), however, this too had no luck, as when it gets to setting up the browser with `const browser = await chromium.launch();` in an external function, playwright seems to exit with no errors being thrown.  My assumption is that the browser setup needs to be within a test context, though that is just a theory.

Any advice on how I can get the desired results would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.