# Dynamically generate Playwright test asynchronously, shows No test found

Tags: typescript, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-typescript, parameterized-tests

The Playwright documentation has a parameterize sample like this. It works:

```
const people = ['Alice', 'Bob'];
for (const name of people) {
  test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
    // ...
  });
  // You can also do it with test.describe() or with multiple tests as long the test name is unique.
}
```

However, I want to get data array before each test，and generate test loop

```
//data like data[] = [{name:'Alice',age:'20'},..]
let data: any[] = []; 

test.beforeEach(async ({ request }) => {
    
    data = await getData(request);
});

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  test(`testing with ${name}`, async (page) => {
    // ...
  });

}
```

In visual studio code, It shows the error: No Test found

But it works when I assign a exact value `let data: any[] =[{name:'Alice',age:'20'}];`.

I test similar case
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9916
[How do I properly run individual Playwright tests from a dynamic array of built urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787926/how-do-i-properly-run-individual-playwright-tests-from-a-dynamic-array-of-built)

Comment: Does your test file have `.spec.` or `.test.` in the filename?

Does the test file exist in a location that will be picked up by your playwright.config file?

Comment: yes, file name is xxx.spec.ts. It works  when i assign exact value, let data: any[] =[{name:'Alice',age:'20'}]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly run individual Playwright tests from a dynamic array of built urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787926/how-do-i-properly-run-individual-playwright-tests-from-a-dynamic-array-of-built)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that Playwright runs the test code twice. The first pass is synchronous, presumably used to detect the number of `test()` calls. The second pass actually executes the tests. Logging something in the top-level of the test file shows this two-step process.

Unfortunately, at the current time, there's no obvious way to use async code at the top level during the initial test detection step.

This works:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

(async () => {
  for (const name of ["a", "b", "c"]) {
    test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
      // ...
    });
  }
})();
```

but this doesn't detect tests:

```js
import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";
import {test} from "@playwright/test";

(async () => {
  await setTimeout(0); // actually do something async
  for (const name of ["a", "b", "c"]) {
    test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
      // ...
    });
  }
})();
```

Furthermore, `before` hooks aren't involved as part of the test discovery process. The following code

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test";

console.log("TEST SUITE");
test.beforeAll(() => console.log("BEFORE"));

for (const name of ["a", "b", "c"]) {
  test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
    // ...
  });
}
```

outputs:

```
$ npx playwright test
TEST SUITE

Running 3 tests using 1 worker

TEST SUITE
  ✓  1 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with a (5ms)
BEFORE
  ✓  2 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with b (4ms)
  ✓  3 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with c (2ms)

  3 passed (270ms)
```

According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9916#issuecomment-957189853), one workaround is to use `test.step()`:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test";

let people = [];

test.beforeAll(async ({request}) => {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const response = await request.get(url);
  people = (await response.json()).map(e => e.name);
});

test("test", async () => {
  for (const name of people) {
    await test.step(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
      // ...
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is the output is missing the test case names:

```
$ npx playwright test

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:11:5 › test (8ms)

  1 passed (407ms)
```

Another workaround is to generate the data in a separate script before running the tests, store it in a file and read the file synchronously at the start of the tests. For example:

generate-people-data.js:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");

(async () => {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const people = (await response.json()).map(e => e.name);
  await fs.writeFile("people.json", JSON.stringify(people));
})();
```

people.test.js:

```js
import fs from "node:fs";
import {test} from "@playwright/test";

const json = fs.readFileSync("people.json", {encoding: "utf-8"});
const people = JSON.parse(json);

for (const name of people) {
  test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Run:

```
$ node generate-people-data && npx playwright test

Running 10 tests using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Leanne Graham (9ms)
  ✓  2 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Ervin Howell (4ms)
  ✓  3 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Clementine Bauch (1ms)
  ✓  4 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Patricia Lebsack (1ms)
  ✓  5 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Chelsey Dietrich (1ms)
  ✓  6 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Mrs. Dennis Schulist (1ms)
  ✓  7 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Kurtis Weissnat (1ms)
  ✓  8 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Nicholas Runolfsdottir V (1ms)
  ✓  9 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Glenna Reichert (1ms)
  ✓  10 pw.test.js:7:7 › testing with Clementina DuBuque (3ms)

  10 passed (253ms)
```

If you don't like the `&&`, you can run `npx playwright test` as the final step of the generator script.

Another option is the [synchronous fetch approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76526490/6243352) from the other thread.

Perhaps there's a more elegant approach in the current version, or future versions of Playwright will support async test detection.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bad solution which is define length of Array

```
let data: any[] = new Array(10);
```

Then the tests can be determined by VScode

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  test(`testing with ${name}`, async page => {
    if (data[i] !== undefined) {
      // test
    }
    // ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to see the workaround. Nitpick: VSCode is just an editor. Playwright is the library that detects the tests.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using beforeEach hook and most probably `getData` method is assigning undefined value to `data` or `data` length is zero. 
I recommend you debugging what's being assigned to `data` in beforeEach hook. 
 
One more important thing: beforEach hook run once before EACH test. In your case,

1. your test starts with and empty array `data`;
2. Your hook works once;
3. But since `data` is empty, test run stops and process exits with error: `No Test found`.

Solution:

```js
import { test } from '@playwright/test';
import { getData } from '../utils/getData';

test.describe('Some feature', () => {
  let data: string[] = [];
  data = getData(); // Assuming it returns an array of strings

  data.forEach(testName => {
    test(`Test name: ${testName}`, () => {
      console.log('Logging test name:', testName);
    });
  });
});
```

It looks like the length of the `data` should be more than 0 before the tests start. Otherwise, since the array is empty and tests in the loop iteration won't be triggered.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you implemented `request` fixture. If that doesn't work, import it into the module and pass it directly to `getData`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unfortunately. The error I get is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` referring to `data.length`. It'd be cool/optimal if this worked though. Typo: `beforAll`.

Comment: It could be. Can you try debugging `request`? check if it is not undefined, or you are getting it with right structure. Next thing is to make sure `getData` is working correctly, make sure it throws error if something is wrong so that you know where your application is failing.

Comment: It's unrelated to `request`, it fails even if `data = ["a", "b", "c"]`, so the fundamental setup here appears not to work regardless of `getData`. Did you try running this code yourself to confirm that it worked? The problem is described in my answer: test detection is a two step process, so the first step doesn't execute hooks, and async code is basically disallowed.

Comment: I updated the solution. It worked for me. You should make sure `data` has length before the tests start.

Comment: Your update removes `async`/`await`, which is what the question is about. Can you update to use that? Your answer still says "Solution: Use `test.beforeAll`" but that's no longer in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257186/discussion-between-jkalandarov-and-ggorlen).